# Dynamic forms in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

Im working on some dynamic forms using AngularJs and appear to have gotten a bit stuck with validation and the form "name" registering on the scope.

What I'm looking to achieve is following.

`<my-form-helper form="someObjectWhichRepresentsFormItems" handle-submit="true">`

When the handel-submit is true, I would like the directive to include a  wrapper around the elements the directive normally creates (a list of inputs, etc)

The problem is, when ever I dynamically add the `<form>` in the template, the scope does not see the form, however if I simply put in the form tag every time it does..

Also, my ideal solution was to use the directive to wrap the element in a `<form>` tag using the link function however the result was the same and I can re-look at this once I have it working from within the template.

E.g

```
<form name="testForm" ng-if="handelSubmit" >
```

Vs

```
<form name="testForm">
```

in the my-form-helper directives controller function the scope

```
.directive('myFormHelper', function ($http, $compile) {

return {

    controller: function($scope){

        $scope.submit = function(){

            // Trying to access $scope.testForm
            // only works if I take out the ng-if,
            // even when handelSubmit == true

            console.log($scope);
            alert('Form submitted..');
            $scope.form.submitted = true;
        }

        $scope.cancel = function(){
            alert('Form canceled..');
        }

    },
    templateUrl: 'app/forms/directive-templates/form/form.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        form:'=',
        handelSubmit:'='
    }
};
});
```

Html tempalte is

```
<form name="testForm" ng-if="handelSubmit" >
<!-- The for name derly should be name="{{form.name}}" -->
<div ng-repeat="field in form.fields">
    <form-field field="field">
</div>

<div class="form-actions" ng-show="handelSubmit">>
    <button type="button"  ng-click="submit()">Submit Form</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>

</form>

<div ng-if="!handelSubmit">
  <div ng-repeat="field in form.fields">
    <form-field field="field">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle? This will help us understand where your problem is.

Comment: From what I can see now is that you are passing attribute `handle-submit="true"` and try to adapt `handelSubmit` in your directive. Try to swap the `l` and `e` or use `handelSubmit:'=handleSubmit'` ;)

Comment: Also- could this have to do with ng-if creating new scope? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/kPRzdcrIzNw/cNaJdguCNeYJ